# What is special about collider's designed collision energies?

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

For example, LHC at Geneva can achieve collisions with energy up to 14 TeV. Why did we set it at this amount?

Comment: It was what governments will willing to pay for.

Comment: Answer to another question is here - [Restarting the LHC: Why 13 Tev?](https://home.cern/science/engineering/restarting-lhc-why-13-tev)

Comment: To zeroth order, the collision energy of a circular collider is set by the size of the ring and the strength of the magnets that bend charged particles around the ring. (Stronger magnets can bend higher energy particles in the same ring). So given your budget and the state of magnet technology, you build the biggest ring with the best magnets you can.

Comment: [From where this number of 14 Tev has arised for proton-proton head on collision in LHC?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31446/37364)

Answer (score 1):

In general:

Particle accelerators represent the state of the art in the energy realm at the time they are being designed, where the energy performance must be at least a rough match to the amount the funding agencies are willing to spend on them.

The energy goal is chosen to permit the investigations of fundamental physics of greatest interest at the time- so for example, the SLAC was pitched in the early 1960's as a means of probing the insides of hadrons at distance scales which were expected to resolve their (suspected) internal structure. The funding had to be carefully finessed to meet the energy scale requirement without breaking the bank, and the project overall was a resounding success.

With time, the state of the art advances and then upgrades get planned. Their funding is justified by the value of the new physics which the upgrade will permit, and all of that is contained in the grant proposals that get subsequently written. If those proposals are sufficiently compelling, the money gets handed over.